# How to display scaled image without anti-aliasing?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, direct2d, sharpdx

**Question**

How can I scale an image in XAML quickly without anti-aliasing applied?

**Background**

I am trying to make a pixel editor as a Windows 8 XAML/C# app. I'm using c#/XAML because most of my experience is with c#/WPF.

- **Method 1:** WriteableBitmap + Image control. 
   
   Originally, I used a WriteableBitmap to store and edit an image. That image is displayed in a resized XAML Image control. The problem is that the image does not get scaled properly because of anti-aliasing. (XAML does not seem to provide the BitmapScalingOptions that are available in WPF) 
   
   [image: anti-aliased version]
- **Method 2:** Redrawn WriteableBitmap + Image control. 
   
   Next I tried writing my own scaling, where I take my original image and write to a larger WriteableBitmap so that the scaled image is pixelated. The scaled image is then presented inside a XAML Image control. This process is slow and inefficient. 
   
   [image]
- **Method 3:** SharpDX + Direct2d ?? 
   
   I am pretty sure a solution exists somewhere between SharpDx, SurfaceImageSource, and Direct2d. Event still, I can't quite figure out how to display a SharpDx.WIC.Bitmap inside a Windows.UI.Xaml Image control, and am generally getting lost in the documentation.

What exactly is a recommended setup for achieving my desired end? Are there c# samples available which might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean by scaling it by resizing it with the mouse or just with a button click to auto scale to a predetermined size.

But the thing you can do is to use an Image panel and then, just set it to `image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;` so if you override and create a method for the Resize event of the Image Panel, your image will take the size to fill the Image panel.

Comment: This method does not work because of the anti-aliasing I mentioned above. I will add more details to my question...